# How to get JSON from googlemaps url

Tags: javascript, php, android, json

As you can see [here](http://www.caffenero.com.tr/index.php?arcBI=21), I need those markers values such as lat lng address.

From that link, i tried to go to [those](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?ll=41.042268%2C29.001695&spn=0.06531%2C0.072004&hl=en&t=m&vpsrc=6&msa=0&source=embed&ie=UTF8&mid=zsrW6PXLEpZk.kTAwhQ8bgERs) link. But still can not inspect anything.

i tried this in Js but it did not return anything

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?ll=41.042268%2C29.001695&spn=0.06531%2C0.072004&hl=en&t=m&vpsrc=6&msa=0&source=embed&ie=UTF8&mid=zsrW6PXLEpZk.kTAwhQ8bgERs" + "&sensor=false";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
        alert(adress);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CursedChico/NNuDe/341/

How can i get? I am used to Js, angularjs, java and android.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get markers data from that url you provided, it uses kml format to get values. Anyways, you want to get location, address etc. Basically you want informations of all markers. Here is the solution:

**1)** Get KML file of the map.

### What is KML data?

> KML is a file format used to display geographic data in an Earth
>   browser such as Google Earth

In your link, you can download it by clicking left menu->download kml->export to kml and you have the kml file. Than parse the kml data into json using a parser like [this](http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/).

**2)** Check if the company let you use JSONP

If the page you are looking for have JSONP set, you can easily retrieve data by injecting JSONP link into your HTML as a script and get than using the callback function. **[Here](http://codepen.io/cmlonder/pen/xVJrMj)** is a working project which gets lat and long datas by calling JSONP.

```js
function setJSONP(code) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://www.nike.com/store-locator/locations?jsoncallback=callback" +
                 "&country_code=US" +
                 "&format=JSON" +
                 "&type=country" +
                 "&_=1461335132869";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }
```

> ?jsoncallback=***yourFunctionName***

then use your function, in this example **callback()** is our function.

```js
function callback(data) {
   //use data here which is returned JSON from server
   var lat = data.lat;
   ...
}
```